# Непонятки с БЭМ

Tags: html, css, sass, бэм

Есть например примитивное меню в котором есть разделители в виде вертикальных полос. Я делаю это с помощью бордера вот так

```
.navbar
max-width: 725px
float: left
background: transparent
border: none
&__li:not(:last-child)
    border-right: 1px solid white
```

А вот код меню

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="navbar__li active"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">О нас</a></li>
          <li class="navbar__li"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">Наши услуги</a></li>
          <li class="navbar__li"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
          <li class="navbar__li"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">Акция</a></li>
          <li class="navbar__li"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
```

А если я захочу подействовать на допустим на ссылку в последнем элементе li как мне поступить? Это может понадобиться если я этот разделитель буду задавать не в li, а в самой ссылке a. Ну или я например буду писать стиль чего либо.

На пример модального окна

```
.modal-green
  &__button
    background: green
  &__link
    color: green
```

Comment: А можете чётко сформулировать именно вопрос? Желательно в заголовке. Потому что я не понимаю, что вы хотите спросить.

Comment: я захочу подействовать на допустим на ссылку в последнем элементе li как мне поступить?

Comment: Что значит подействовать на ссылку?

Comment: задать стиль для ссылки

Comment: Это же у вас не чистый CSS, а какой-то препроцессор. Добавьте метку о нём.

Comment: добавил, это sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с бэм, то можно так:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="navbar__li active"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">О нас</a></li>
  <li class="navbar__li"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">Наши услуги</a></li>
  <li class="navbar__li"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
  <li class="navbar__li"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">Акция</a></li>
  <li class="navbar__li navbar__li_last"><a class="navbar__link" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

Т.е. добавить последнему элементу модификатор `navbar__li_last` и его стилизовать.

Либо использовать `&__li:last-child`:

```
.navbar
...
&__li
    border-right: 1px solid white
&__li:last-child
    border-right: none
```

При этом всем лишкам Вы задаете необходимые стили, а последнему элементу уже или отменяете или задаете свои стили, соответственно и для ссылки внутри лишки.

Пример для ссылки:

```
&__li:last-child
  a
    border: none
```

или

```
<li class="navbar__li"><a class="navbar__link navbar__link_last" href="#">Контакты</a></li>

navbar__link_last
  border: none
```

[+ поддержка Вашего :not()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list), может быть это плохая идея использовать его!

Comment: все это я реализовал с помощью &__li:not(:last-child)
    border-right: 1px solid white

Comment: Тогда в чем вопрос?!

Comment: все это я реализовал с помощью
 &__li:not(:last-child)
    border-right: 1px solid white
но вопрос в том чтобы подействовать именно на ссылку. Но в принципе если дать ей модификатор __link_last но в принципе это наверное какое-то решение. Будем считать вопрос закрытым) 
Блин много документации по БЭМ а примеров не очень много)

Comment: бэм на сколько я понял не допускает вложености

Comment: Добавила же и для бэм `navbar__link_last
  border: none`